# Trouble passing a $_GET

Tags: php, get

So I have this php script that will basically read a director and turn it into a list for me to display in a div:

```
<?php
            foreach ($entries as $entry => $is_dir) {
            $class_name = $is_dir ? 'directory' : 'file';
            $escaped_entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);
            printf('<li class="%s"><form action="page.php" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="stuff" value="%s"><input type="submit" value="%s"></form></li>' . "\n", $class_name, $escaped_entry, $escaped_entry);
            }
        ?>
```

What I cant figure out is how to get the variable into the next script. It is showing up in the url of the next page however I cant puzzle out how to get it into the script which is simply:

```
<?php $page = $_GET["stuff"]; include $page; ?>
```

CANT GET THIS should be whatever is being passed from the hidden input field from the above script. How do I get THAT value from the URL or get it to pass into the new script?

I know this is going to be an easy answer and im going to beat my head on the wall for it but Im totally lost here! Any and all help would be appreciated! And I know there are several other questions on here about get method but I didnt see any that were quite like this one, or Im dumb.

EDIT: Errrr I basically overcomplicated the whole situation and tried to get way more fancy than what was needed! I have Changed the above code to reflect what is right and working! For the most part I had #escaped_entry going into the form action attribute as well as the hidden inputs name field...long story short its all good now!

Comment: try `<?php $page = $_GET["THIS"]; include $page; ?>`, also there is a difference between string with `'` and `"` in `"` you can place variable like `"$page"` but with `'$page'` it will just return `$page`

Comment: Ive tried that...I will edit the question to reflect more clearly

Comment: Please consider what happens if someone sets `$_GET['THIS']` TO `/path/to/a/very/secret/file`. This is a **very** big potential security hole.

Comment: Thank you guys, I edited the original post to reflect my issue a bit more clearly.

Comment: @ceejayoz I mistyped with I put THIS in there and just threw it in not thinking about it being reserved. I hope I NEVER accidentally give that kind of full blown access to anything! But good heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try do not to use 'this' word, and also try not to use spaces in your input names.
'this' is reserved word in php.
You can simplify your code and make something like this:

```
 <?php
    foreach ($entries as $entry => $is_dir) {
       $class_name = $is_dir ? 'directory' : 'file';
       $escaped_entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);
       $url = 'http://domain.com/yourscriptname.php?Mydir='.$escaped_entry;
       printf('<li class="%s"><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $class_name, $url,$escaped_entry);
    }
?>
```

Then in yourscriptname.php your $escaped_entry will be stored in $_GET['Mydir'];

For dummies:
Everything that you have in your url after ? (question mark), called "QUERY_STRING" and can be accessed via $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. This is serialized collection of $key=>$value pairs of variables, delimited by & (ampersand) that are stored in $_GET var as array.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: When I tried $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] All I can get returned is something=something they will both be the same thing but I realy just need what comes AFTER the =. Will your method return just that to $GET_['Mydir']?

Comment: `?Mydir='.$escaped_entry;` means that `$GET_['Mydir'] = $escaped_entry;`. try to do this: go to http://yourdomain.com/yourscriptname.php?var1=value1&var2=some%20text&some_new_var=oh%20here%20it%20goes&can_pass_array[]=array%20value&can_pass_array[array_key]=array%20element%20with%20key and then write in yourscriptname.php `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_GET);` and compare your query string with GET array

Comment: I got everything figured out and its working now. I edited the OP with the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$page = basename($_GET["THIS"]);
include $page;
```

basename() is **essential** and quotes are wrong when addressing a variable.

Comment: note that there isn't a `;` after `$page = basename(...)` is... aah nevermind, you fixed it :)